# SDK for ZKteco attendance machine (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, sdk, zkteco

I'm new to ZKteco device integration. Can anyone provide me please a link  for vb.net SDK for ZKTeco time keeper machines? I need to write a code for attendance monitoring but I cant find one. Thank you in advance for any lead!

I only found SDK for C# and C++ which I am not familiar with.

Comment: Have a look at [Convert.NET](https://fishcodelib.com/Convert.htm) which does a pretty good job translating C# <-> VB.NET. It might not convert the C# code error free, but in my experience, if that's the case, the resulting VB.NET code is close enough that you can figure out how to correct/complete it. That said, I recommend to get familiar with the basics of C#, which shouldn't take too long. You'll come across a lot of samples only available in C#. Being able to easily adapt those, will pay off in the long run.